# Is there diminishing returns on Stache?

Tags: mario-and-luigi-paper-jam

I know that Stache is used to calculate lucky hit and possibly shop price reduction, but is there a reason to ever stop increasing it (ie, with beans)? Does it stop being as beneficial at some number, or can I reach a 100% lucky hit rate?